# Actual content send to OpenAI and Prompt Injection

Tags: langchain

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.9, model=llm_model, verbose=True)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    "What is the best name to describe \
    a company that makes {product}?"
)
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)

product = "Queen Size Sheet Set"
chain.run(product)

chain.prompt
```

1. how do I see the actual command send to openai endpoint
2. does the langchain use delimiter like `this is the input:###{prompt}###` to prevent prompt injection

Answer (score 0):

From the program perspective that you have shared you check below two things

1. Details of prompt
2. Response

   ```
   print("\nChain=> ",chain.prompt
   print("\nResponse=> ",chain.run(product))
   ```

To check the **OpenAI request and response (actual content)**, you can use the curl command to make a POST request to the OpenAI Chat API endpoint. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
 curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" --request POST --data '{"message": "Your message here"}' https://chat.openai.com/chat
```

Replace "Your message here" with the message you want to send to the OpenAI model. The response will be returned in JSON format.

Here is an example of the response:

```
{
 "response": "The response from the OpenAI model"
}
```

The response field contains the generated response from the model

**Prerequiste - OpenAI Key has be set as environment variable** before you make a api call

Lastly, regarding **prompt injection**, Langchain uses Rebuff (its in alpha phase). It's an open-source framework designed to detect and guard against PI attacks in LLM applications

It uses several defense mechanisms:

1. Heuristics: Filters out potential malicious input before it reaches
   the LLM.
2. LLM-based detection: Uses an LLM to scrutinize incoming
   prompts for possible attacks.
3. VectorDB: Stores embeddings of past
   attacks, helping recognize and prevent future similar attacks.
4. Canary tokens: Adds these tokens to prompts to catch leakages, which
   then informs the framework about the incoming prompt's embeddings
   for future prevention.

More details can be found on blog here https://blog.langchain.dev/rebuff/